# Why is my django view returning a zero obejct list?

Tags: django

I might be lazy or am blind! but the following code is returning ZERO!
items, while very well i know there is some items in the list,

View:

```
def post_answer(request, quest_id=None):
    answer_list = Answer.objects.filter
(questionis__pk=quest_id).select_related()
    ...
# if a put a print stmt here ( answer_list[0].answer ) there is
# data displayed on the console!!

return render_to_response('myapp/post_answer.html',{'answerobj':answer_list }} )
```

Template post_answer.html:

```
{% regroup answerobj.object_list by answer as ans_list %}{{ ans_list|length }}
....
```

the above code prints 0.

I must be goofing somewhere, pls assist

Paul

Comment: What happens if you put {{ answerobj }} in your template. Does that output anything?

Answer (score 1):

try :
    {% regroup answerobj by answer as ans_list %}{{ ans_list|length }} 
object_list isn't required.